# How to move and group text files based on their content?

Tags: command-line, files, filemanager

Imagine I have 100 text files in Folder X.
30-40 text files contains word "**Cookies**".

I wanna copy all those text files to Folder Y which has word "**Cookies**" inside it.

Which is fast and efficient way to do this using cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will works:

```
grep -l 'Cookies' /Path/to/X/*.txt | xargs -I files mv files /Path/to/Y/
```

- `grep -l 'Cookies' /Path/to/X/*.txt`:

  - will look for all `*.txt` files contains `Cookies`, change it to `*` for any file.
  - `-l` means only print the file names.
- `xargs -I files mv files /Path/to/Y/`

  - will moves them to your desired path.

Or even instead of `xargs` we can use a loop:

```
grep -l 'Cookies' /Path/to/X/*.txt | while read i; do mv "$i" /path/to/x/; done
```